# Distinct from array_agg of text fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following rows:

```
order items_ordered
1     'tshirt,shorts'
1     'shoes,flipflops,'shorts'
2     'dress'
```

I want to group by order and count of unique items ordered (PostgreSQL).

Result:

```
1  4
2  1
```

Order 1 has four unique items because of 'tshirt,shorts,shoes,flipflops'.

I tried:

```
select

distinct array_agg(regexp_split_to_array(items_ordered, ','))

from ALL_FINAL
group by order
```

Error:

> cannot accumulate arrays of different dimensionality

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's not working?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LATERAL` combined with unnested array:

```
select "order", COUNT(DISTINCT c) AS cnt
from ALL_FINAL
,LATERAL (SELECT unnest(regexp_split_to_array(items_ordered, ','))) s(c)
group by "order";
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/ACD57349)**

---

Anyway you should rethink your schema design. Storing values as CSV is not best idea.